# Connection error to sql server when doing massive queries with sqlsrv

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, sqlsrv

i was wondering if anyone knows why i am getting the following error.

I have an application doing massive queries to a SQL 2008 Server. The main application runs over PHP on linux , I call many php scripts simultanously to a windows server running PHP over xampp, this server queries the sql database and this is where I am getting the error.
On this windows server I hava PHP 5.4.4  with the sqlsrv extension.  I have the sql server configured to handle unlimited connections. however when I send many API calls (thousands) i eventually start getting connection errors like the one below,

Unable to connect to server

I read that mssql conection can be tuned with the max_procs config, however I am using sqlsrv extension instead and I havent found any info regarding this .

Has anyone experienced this issue before.

Thanks in advanced.